# Auto-updating linked smart objects in files that were closed at the moment of the update

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, cc-2014

Photoshop CC 2014 introduces Linked Smart Object. While this is a very useful feature by itself, I would love to know if there's a way to set it so that whenever I open a file that contains a linked smart object but wasn't open when the linked document changed, the smart object layer will also automatically update.

Photoshop currently only updates linked smart objects in files that are open when you make the change, and all other files require manual updating. Is there a way to set it to update automatically in this case as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Make a new `.jsx` file in the `Presets/Scripts/Event Scripts Only` folder ( inside the PS application folder ).
2. Paste in the following code:

---

```
// Update all modified content
var idplacedLayerUpdateAllModified = stringIDToTypeID( "placedLayerUpdateAllModified" );
executeAction( idplacedLayerUpdateAllModified, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
```

---

3. Name the file: `Update All Modified Content.jsx`
4. In `File > Scripts > Scripts events manager...` add the script to be triggered on `Open document` and it's done.

[image]

Comment: This is great, though if you open a .png with a locked background layer this prompts an error window. Is there a way for this to only run if you open a .psd?

Comment: @ChrisZimnowski Added inscructions on how to do it properly, so that it won't trigger any errors.

Answer (score 2):

This works but you shouldn't select a layer. PS will look for that layer in all documents. You should instead start recording then go to Layer > Smart Objects > Update all Modified Content.