# Script to update linked files before exporting using Photoshop's Image Processing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, batch-processing, photoshop-scripting, smartobject

Related to this treat:
[Auto-updating linked smart objects in files that were closed at the moment of the update](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38662/auto-updating-linked-smart-objects-in-files-that-were-closed-at-the-moment-of-th)

I have linked smart objects in 24 PSD files.

Is there a script I can use with the "Image Processing" function that checks if there has been any changes to the smart objects in the PSD files and first updates the file then saves that file as a JPG? Can this be done by a script instead of manualy opening each PSD file?

Comment: Can't you just create an action that updated all smart objects, then use that for a batch process? (I don't have CC so I'm not sure a smart object update will record, but the linked question implies it does)

Comment: Thank you for solutions. Never before tryed Action-record function. Solved!

Comment: Before the current answer in that question you linked above, I used to have a solution that involved an action, but it was pointed out that if you run that action on a file that only has a background layer, it'll give an error, so I switched the answer to a script that doesn't throw any errors. So, I might actually recommend making an action, where you [run that script](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/38664/2332) and then call that action in the `Image Processor`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an action by pressing the New Action button from the Actions panel, your new action will be recording as soon as you create it. Do all the steps you want to record (i.e. Update all smart layers, resize, export JPG), then stop recording.

You can then use your action as a batch process on a folder of images by going to **File → Automate → Batch...** and selecting your action and the images you want to process.

You can read more about actions here:

- [Photoshop help / Creating actions](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-actions.html)

and batch processing here:

- [Photoshop help / Process a batch of files](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html)